# PHP Deprecated: Non-static method Database::get_json_rows() should not be called statically in

Tags: php, php7

Tengo un error en servidor, cuando subo mi aplicación web, luego de crear las bases de datos e instalar todo me larga en el administrador de la aplicación el siguiente error y no me muestra lo que tengo en la base de datos.

```
GET https://www.paoynestor.ar/gestor/php/servicios/invitados.listado.php 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

El código del Archivo PHP invitados.listado.php

```
    <?php
error_reporting(0);

// Incluir la clase de base de datos
include_once("../classes/class.Database.php");

// Retorna un json
header('Content-Type: application/json');

$sql = "SELECT * FROM invitados ORDER BY nombre ASC";

echo Database::get_json_rows($sql);

?>
```

Mi archivo JavaScript Angularsj de donde hago la petición

```
app.controller('invitadosCtrl', ['$scope','$http', function($scope,$http){

    $scope.invitados = {};
    $scope.posicion = 5; 

    $http.get("php/servicios/invitados.listado.php")
         .success(function(data){

        $scope.invitados = data;
        

    });

    $scope.siguientes = function(){

        if ( $scope.invitados.length > $scope.posicion ) {
            $scope.posicion += 5;

        };
    }
        $scope.anteriores = function(){

        if ($scope.posicion > 5) {
            $scope.posicion -= 5;

        };
    }


}]);
```

En mi servidor local Wamp64 no me larga ningún error, funciona correctamente la app, cuando lo monto en el hosting tengo ese error y no me muestra datos de la base de datos, espero puedan ayudarme, dejo una captura del navegador también.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zlaXY.jpg)

**Error que se encuentra en el log**

---

```
[19-Feb-2021 16:11:50 UTC] PHP Deprecated:  Non-static method Database::get_json_rows() should not be called statically in /home/dggonxa1/public_html/gestor/php/servicios/invitados.listado.php on line 10
```

**Codigo donde modifico el metodo a Static**

```
 <?php
// ======================================================
// Clase: class.Database.php
// Funcion: Se encarga del manejo con la base de datos
// Descripcion: Tiene varias funciones muy útiles para
//              el manejo de registros.
//              
// Ultima Modificación: 17 de marzo de 2015
// ======================================================


class Database{

    private $_connection;
    private $_host = "localhost";
    private $_user = "boda_user";
    private $_pass = "123456";
    private $_db   = "boda_db";


    // Almacenar una unica instancia
    private static $_instancia;



    // ================================================
    // Metodo para obtener instancia de base de datos
    // ================================================
    public static function getInstancia(){

        if(!isset(self::$_instancia)){
            self::$_instancia = new self;
        }

        return self::$_instancia;
    }

    // ================================================
    // Constructor de la clase Base de datos
    // ================================================
    public function __construct(){
        $this->_connection = new mysqli($this->_host,$this->_user,$this->_pass,$this->_db);

        // Manejar error en base de datos
        if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
            trigger_error('Falla en la conexion de base de datos'. mysqli_connect_error(), E_USER_ERROR );
        }
    }

    // Metodo vacio __close para evitar duplicacion
    private function __close(){}

    // Metodo para obtener la conexion a la base de datos
    public function getConnection(){
        return $this->_connection;
    }

    // Metodo que revisa el String SQL
    private function es_string($sql){
        if (!is_string($sql)) {
            trigger_error('class.Database.inc: $SQL enviado no es un string: ' .$sql);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    // ==================================================
    //  Funcion que ejecuta el SQL y retorna un ROW
    //      Esta funcion esta pensada para SQLs, 
    //      que retornen unicamente UNA sola línea
    // ==================================================
    public function get_Row($sql){
        
        if(!self::es_string($sql))
            exit();

        $db = DataBase::getInstancia();
        $mysqli = $db->getConnection();
        $resultado = $mysqli->query($sql);

        if($row = $resultado->fetch_assoc()){
            return $row;
        }else{
            return array();
        }
    }

    // ==================================================
    //  Funcion que ejecuta el SQL y retorna un CURSOR
    //      Esta funcion esta pensada para SQLs, 
    //      que retornen multiples lineas (1 o varias)
    // ==================================================
    public function get_Cursor($sql){

        if(!self::es_string($sql))
            exit();


        $db = DataBase::getInstancia();
        $mysqli = $db->getConnection();

        $resultado = $mysqli->query($sql);
        return $resultado; // Este resultado se puede usar así:  while ($row = $resultado->fetch_assoc()){...}
    }

    // ==================================================
    //  Funcion que ejecuta el SQL y retorna un jSon
    //  data: [{...}] con N cantidad de registros
    // ==================================================
    public static function get_json_rows($sql){

        if(!self::es_string($sql))
            exit();

        $db = DataBase::getInstancia();
        $mysqli = $db->getConnection();

        $resultado = $mysqli->query($sql);

        // Si hay un error en el SQL, este es el error de MySQL
        if (!$resultado ) {
            return "class.Database.class: error ". $mysqli->error;
        }

        
        $i = 0;
        while($row = $resultado->fetch_assoc()){
            $registros[$i]= $row;
            $i++;
        };
        return json_encode( $registros );
    }

    // ==================================================
    //  Funcion que ejecuta el SQL y retorna un jSon
    //  de una sola linea. Ideal para imprimir un
    //  Query que solo retorne una linea
    // ==================================================
    public static function get_json_row($sql){

        if(!self::es_string($sql))
            exit();

        $db = DataBase::getInstancia();
        $mysqli = $db->getConnection();

        $resultado = $mysqli->query($sql);

        // Si hay un error en el SQL, este es el error de MySQL
        if (!$resultado ) {
            return "class.Database.class: error ". $mysqli->error;
        }


        if(!$row = $resultado->fetch_assoc()){
            return "{}";
        }
        return json_encode( $row );
    }

    // ====================================================================
    //  Funcion que ejecuta el SQL y retorna un valor
    //  Ideal para count(*), Sum, cosas que retornen una fila y una columna
    // ====================================================================
    public function get_valor_query($sql,$columna){

        if(!self::es_string($sql,$columna))
            exit();

        $db = DataBase::getInstancia();
        $mysqli = $db->getConnection();

        $resultado = $mysqli->query($sql);

        // Si hay un error en el SQL, este es el error de MySQL
        if (!$resultado ) {
            return "class.Database.class: error ". $mysqli->error;
        }

        $Valor = NULL;
        //Trae el primer valor del arreglo
        if ($row = $resultado->fetch_assoc()) {
            // $Valor = array_values($row)[0];
            $Valor = $row[$columna];
        }

        return $Valor;
    }

    // ====================================================================
    //  Funcion que ejecuta el SQL de inserción, actualización y eliminación
    // ====================================================================
    public function ejecutar_idu($sql){

        if(!self::es_string($sql))
            exit();

        $db = DataBase::getInstancia();
        $mysqli = $db->getConnection();

        if (!$resultado = $mysqli->query($sql) ) {
            return "class.Database.class: error ". $mysqli->error;
        }else{
            return $resultado;
        }

        

        return $resultado;
    }

    // ====================================================================
    //  Funciones para encryptar y desencryptar data: 
    //      crypt_blowfish_bydinvaders
    // ====================================================================
    function crypt($aEncryptar, $digito = 7) {
        $set_salt = './1234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
        $salt = sprintf('$2a$%02d$', $digito);
        for($i = 0; $i < 22; $i++)
        {
            $salt .= $set_salt[mt_rand(0, 22)];
        }
        return crypt($aEncryptar, $salt);
    }

    function uncrypt($Evaluar, $Contra){

        if( crypt($Evaluar, $Contra) == $Contra)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
        
    }

}


?>
```

Comment: Un error 500 refleja algún problema con tu código en el servidor, entonces para poderte ayudar debes ir al log de errores de apache y verificar el mensaje exacto que se generó, entonces venir y agregarlo aqui

Comment: ahi coloque el error que se encuentra en el log

[19-Feb-2021 16:11:50 UTC] PHP Deprecated:  Non-static method Database::get_json_rows() should not be called statically in /home/dggonxa1/public_html/gestor/php/servicios/invitados.listado.php on line 10

Comment: Sabes que en mi servidor local funciona todo correctamente, pero el el hosting me da error, le agregue el método static y me da igual error y no me carga los datos de la base de datos

Comment: El hecho de que te *funcione* en local no quiere decir que esta bien, por otro lado agregando static al método aún así sale el mismo error¿?

Comment: si el mismo error, lo que estuve pensando es que el hosting tenga algún problema en su php, le coloque la misma versión que utilizo en mi wamp pero aun así larga el mismo error,  ahí actualizo con el código donde agrego el static y el error en consola

Answer (score 0):

**El error nace de la forma en que estás llamando al método `get_json_rows()`**, pues de acuerdo con el mensaje del *log*, este no es estático sino que debe tener una sintaxis similar a la siguiente:

```
public function get_json_rows()
{
    /*
        algo de código por aqui
    */
}
```

Entonces, si este esta dentro de la clase `Database` tienes que crear una instancia de la misma para poder usarlo.

1. Opción 1.

   ```
   $objetoInstanciado = new Database();
   $objetoInstanciado->get_json_rows();
   ```
2. Opción 2.

   ```
   (new Database())->get_json_rows();
   ```

Por otro lado

Recuerda que un método esático (*que tiene en su definición la keyword `static` no requiere de una [instancia de la clase para poder usarlo](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.oop5.static.php#language.oop5.static)*), por tanto el método debería estar así:

```
public static function get_json_rows()
{
    /*
        algo de código por aqui
    */
}
```

Y entonces si sería válido el llamado que tratas de hacer.

Finalmente.

Como puedes observar en la propia [doc. de PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.oop5.static.php#language.oop5.static.methods) desde **PHP 7** se generará un *warning* de tipo: **`E_DEPRECATED`** cuando se intente llamar como estático a un método que no lo es.

Answer (score 0):

Para todos, probé con otros proveedores de hosting con php versión 7.3, ya que era la que usaba yo en mi localhost y en teoría era la misma que usaba en el hosting que utilizaba y me daba todos los errores.

Al final probé en otros servidores y funciono sin problemas con el código que tenia originalmente, el error era debido a que al parecer el proveedor de hosting tenia varios errores en su php y no me lo solucionaba. el proveedor es **TOWEBS.COM** por si alguno no quiere pasar por el mismo problema que yo
. **NO LO CONTRATE**

***desde ya muchas gracias a todos por sus aportes***